# How to start Snipping Tool from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the Snipping Tool from the command line. 
I can run it from the Run box, but despite how much I try and different ways to do it I cannot open up the Snipping Tool on Windows 7 from PowerShell. I am sick of having to use the mouse to open up the Snipping Tool.

Start process:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe")
```

Call operator:

```
& "C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe"
```

Dot-sourcing:

```
. C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe
```

Using `Inovke-Item`:

```
ii "C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe"
```

Change to the directory:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ./SnippingTool.exe
```

Comment: I always use the Windows key or Ctrl-Esc and start typing `snip` followed by `Enter`. Fast enough for me and no need for a mouse.

Comment: In Win7, the Snipping tool is bound to a key shortcut: `Win + S`

Comment: Most of the methods you tried work for me (except dot-sourcing, which can't work since it's for PowerShell scripts, not executables). Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Start-Process "c:\windows\sysnative\snippingtool.exe"`

-Edit to add, if you run the x86 (32-bit) powershell console, you'll have to use SysNative because on a 64-bit system, the C:\Windows\System32 is actually 64-bit processes.  So open the x64 Powershell console, and C:\Windows\System32 will work as expected.  Additionally, C:\Windows\Syswow64 contains 32 bit binaries.  Be safe and use `C:\Windows\SysNative` and you won't have to think about this type of thing.

Comment: You're welcome, if you want the ultimate in easy to access shortcuts try right clicking the desktop > New ShortCut > Location C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe > then right click that new shortcut > Properties and for Shortcut key press any key to create a keyboard shortcut for the shortcut.  For example, press Z and when you press `CTRL + ALT + Z` snipping tool will open.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
PS C:\> cd C:\Windows\System32
PS C:\Windows\System32> .\SnippingTool.exe
```

If you are using PowerShell ISE, try opening a new instance and running it. 
Further check if the file is located there.